# How to implement context menus for custom ListViews?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

How does one register a ListView for a context menu when using a custom ListView based on BaseAdapter?

I tried         `registerForContextMenu(getListView());`, but this doesn't seem to work. I'm using ListView14.java from API Demos.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}




@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.tag_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.tagView:
  //  editNote(info.id);
    return true;
  case R.id.tagRename:
   // deleteNote(info.id);
    return true;
  case R.id.tagDelete:
       // deleteNote(info.id);
        return true;
  default:
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `registerForContextMenu(getListView())`, try naming your listview in onCreate and using that reference:

```
Listview myListView = (Listview) findViewById(R.id.myListView); //or use any other constructor
registerForContextMenu(myListView);
```

This works for all the items in my adapter-fed Gridview (although it's turning out to be impossible to then properly adding a contextmenu to the gridview itself which registers longclicks on the empty gridview items, but that's another story altogether :) ), and I'd imagine a Listview to work the same.